# Calculating accuracy from two columns in R, creating summary table

Tags: r, dataframe

Note: I'm pretty new at this. 
I have a data frame (df) in R

```
INDIVIDUALS CURRENT INFERRED 
pop1_1 1 1
pop1_2 1 1 
pop1_3 1 2
pop2_1 2 3
pop2_2 2 2
pop2_3 2 2
pop3_1 3 1
pop3_2 3 2
pop3_3 3 3
```

showing unique individuals labelled by a class (pop), the class to which they actually belong in (CURRENT) and the class to which they were placed by an algorithm (INFERRED).

What I would like is a summary of the accuracy, both by class and overall. So with the above example, I'd like something that looks like:

```
POP CORRECT ACCURACY
pop1 2 66.7
pop2 2 66.7
pop3 1 33.3 
OVERALL 5 55.6
```

So far I have this for the overall calculation:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(reducedresults))
{reducedresults[,i]=as.vector(reducedresults[,i])}
correct<-ifelse(reducedresults$CURRENT==reducedresults$INFERRED,1,0)
accuracy<-sum(correct)/length(correct)*100
```

I figured I could specify rows to find the accuracy for each class, but I'm not sure how to coerce it into the summary table, or if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: For starters, its always a good idea to store your group variable (here pop) separate from your individual within group variable (1,2,3) This makes it easier to aggregate. You do this here with something like `cbind(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$individuals), split="_")), df)`, but better to start off with them separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a grouping variable

```
> df$GROUP <- sub('_.*', '', as.character(df$INDIVIDUALS))
```

then you can use `table` to calculate absolute and relative frequencies

```
> tab <- with(df, table(GROUP, CORRECT=CURRENT == INFERRED))
> addmargins(tab)
      CORRECT
GROUP  FALSE TRUE Sum
  pop1     1    2   3
  pop2     1    2   3
  pop3     2    1   3
  Sum      4    5   9
> prop.table(tab, margin=1)
      CORRECT
GROUP      FALSE      TRUE
  pop1 0.3333333 0.6666667
  pop2 0.3333333 0.6666667
  pop3 0.6666667 0.3333333
> prop.table(colSums(tab))
    FALSE      TRUE 
0.4444444 0.5555556
```